# How to pass no argument into pragma comment in c++

Tags: c++, pragma

I want my program to show the console window if it detects the solution configuration is debug. If it detects release, then the console window should not show up

```
#include "Window.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Window Game;

#if defined(_DEBUG)
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:console /ENTRY:")
    Game.run();
#else
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
    Game.run();
#endif
}
```

The source code above doesn't work because:

```
LNK1146 no argument specified with option '/ENTRY:'
```

So I want to know how to pass no argument in #pragma comment (or just improve this source code in general)

(using Visual Studio 2023 and C++ 20)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Actually, why bother with `/ENTRY` at all?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`/ENTRY` flag for MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-170) always has to be followed by `:function_name`. So if you want to keep the default, just don't pass `/ENTRY` at all for that case:

```cpp
#include "Window.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Window Game;

#if defined(_DEBUG)
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:console")
    Game.run();
#else
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
    Game.run();
#endif
}
```